# buildozer/Kivy NONETYPE splitlines error

Tags: android, kivy, buildozer

When I try to compile my APK in the VM version of Buildozer I am getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 11, in <module>
load_entry_point('buildozer==0.33', 'console_scripts', 'buildozer')()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/scripts/client.py",         line 13, in main
Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 1058, in run_command
self.target.run_commands(args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 91, in run_commands
func(args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 101, in cmd_debug
self.buildozer.prepare_for_build()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 176, in prepare_for_build
self.target.install_platform()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 470, in install_platform
self._install_android_packages()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 407, in _install_android_packages
packages = self._android_list_sdk()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 336, in _android_list_sdk
for x in available_packages.splitlines()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'splitlines'
```

I have not found an answer anywhere that relates to this issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Problem buildozer [can't run](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/blob/6a8209d0817b47fb5d3ec538cceb308881113100/buildozer/targets/android.py#L327) android sdk command to get list of available packages. Have you changed `android.sdk` or `android.sdk_path` options in your `buildozer.spec` file?

Comment: I had entered a build directory that it didn't like, thank you !